# How to I manipulate the table to this shape?

Tags: html, css

I need to create this shape In HTML.
I just learned about colspan and rowspan but this eating my mind...
thanks for help.

Table:
[image]

Comment: Do you need a table like this, or you need to draw it using canvas? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_rowspan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot merge a td like the inverted  L-shape. Instead this can be done by adjusting border style.

```css
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table width="300" border="1px">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" height="30" style="border-bottom: 0">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="30" style="border-top: 0">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td height="200">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

without `rowspan` or `colspan` , `:first-child` and `+` selector can help too.

[no matters the numbers of row or column ;)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaPmJd)

```css
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border:solid;
}
th, td {
  min-width:3em;
  height:3em;
}

tr td:first-child {
  border-right:solid;
}
th + th {
  border-bottom:solid
}
```

```html
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th></th>
   <th></th>
   <th></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```